# Typesafe Console Configuration for Java application

Tags: java, playframework, akka, typesafe-stack, typesafe

I have an application using play that is built using Java. I wish to use the Typesafe Console for my application to monitor Akka, However I am unable to configure it as I am unable to find configuration details for Java. Also, couldn't find any references to able Typesafe console for java application.

I googled and found sample showing Typesafe console configurations for a Scala application. Tried following the same guidelines for java but it didn't yield any result.

I have downloaded binary distribution and written a sample application in Java. Made changes in `build.scala` referring Scala sample application and then started Atmos(bin/typesafe-console atmos) & Console UI (bin/typesafe-console ui).
I'm getting error :

```
[info] Running com.typesafe.atmos.sample.GreetingApplication 
[error] No such file or class on classpath: com.typesafe.atmos.sample.GreetingApplication
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

Any help on `Build.scala` configuration for Java application will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just to add that I am a Play newbie and unable to fathom the sbt configurations given on the github link you posted as they are in Scala. I am used to the Play Console for my daily build tasks and requirements.
I wish to proceed in the rightful direction using Java for my application & its configuration. Could you please provide me similar helpful configuration in Java ?

Answer (score 3):

Received response from '**Peter Vlugter**' on another forum for the same problem.
Deeply grateful to him for his valuable contribution.

> Configuration is the same for Java as it is for Scala.
>
> Play projects use sbt, whether they're Scala or Java projects, and sbt
>   configuration is always in Scala.
>
> I've created a sample project that adds Typesafe Console to a Play
>   Java project:
>
> https://github.com/pvlugter/hello-atmos-play-java
>
> I've started with the java hello world sample project:
>
> https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.1.3/samples/java/helloworld
>
> I've added a simple actor to this sample to be traced. I assume you
>   have an Akka actor system to trace within your Play application.
>
> Adding the developer Typesafe Console to the project with sbt-atmos is
>   in this commit:
>
> https://github.com/pvlugter/hello-atmos-play-java/commit/b9d6e5590e10b2ac8cbbb6254b3298a73e356799
>
> Cheers,
> Peter Vlugter